# Play console crash report tgkill+8

Tags: android, native

here is the crash i am getting in play console. how can i trace this crash.

```
backtrace:
  native: pc 000000000006bc30  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
  native: pc 00000000000690cc  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+64)
  native: pc 0000000000023e68  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+24)
  native: pc 000000000001c8ec  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+52)
  native: pc 0000000000756d08  /data/app/com.android.chrome-1/base.apk
```

why this com.android.chrome-1/base.apk crash occurs in my app?

Comment: I'm also hunting down this problem, my app doesn't show Google ads but use WebView for YouTube video.  My code has been running for years.  But this happened recently.  I don't have solution yet.  Please see this thread which suggest Chrome to blame:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/I6giN0VbVa0

Comment: yes, you are right, it was some error in Google ads SDK or in Chrome, nowadays not getting this crash in the console.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely because you use a [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) in your app. I'd add some logging to your app about what you are sending to the webview, and try to reproduce it.

Comment: It was Google Ads SDK that uses WebView. And i don't find any specific reason that specifies that this problem is from Chrome or From Ads SDK